# Как сделать скрипт крушения самолета на Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Я использую версию Unity 2021 года. И вот я хочу сделать скрипт для самолета. Cамолет из пакета Standard Assets 2018 года. Так вот работать должно так: При столкновении самолета об поверхность на большой скорости он должен уничтожаться и сцена должна перезапускаться. Как это возможно сделать ?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы что-то сделать надо начать это делать, начните(научите самолёт лететь,  научите врезаться, научите уничтожаться на скорости и тп) и когда столкнётесь с конкретной проблемой(например почему самолёт ведет себя "так", а не "вот так", я хотел именно "так", вот мой код, и я пробовал "вот это", но у меня не получилось "потому что"), разбирайтесь, спрашивайте.

Comment: Летать он умеет изначально. Только вот мне было интересно можно ли как-то это реализовать, но ладно буду думать.